# How to sort a Pandas DataFrame by index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

When there is a DataFrame like the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(1, index=[100, 29, 234, 1, 150], columns=['A'])
```

How can I sort this dataframe by index with each combination of index and column value intact?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Dataframes have a `sort_index` method which returns a copy by default. Pass `inplace=True` to operate in place.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index=[100, 29, 234, 1, 150], columns=['A'])
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df.to_string())
```

Gives me:

```
     A
1    4
29   2
100  1
150  5
234  3
```

Comment: Note - `inplace` is not recommended : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529

Answer (score 19):

Slightly more compact:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index=[100, 29, 234, 1, 150], columns=['A'])
df = df.sort_index()
print(df)
```

Note:

- `sort` has been deprecated, replaced by `sort_index` for this scenario
- preferable not to use `inplace` as it is usually harder to read and prevents chaining. See explanation in answer here:
  [Pandas: peculiar performance drop for inplace rename after dropna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532302/pandas-peculiar-performance-drop-for-inplace-rename-after-dropna)

Answer (score 1):

If the DataFrame **index has name**, then you can use `sort_values()` to sort by the name as well. For example, if the index is named `lvl_0`, you can sort by this name. This particular case is common if the dataframe is obtained from a `groupby` or a `pivot_table` operation.

```py
df = df.sort_values('lvl_0')
```

[image: res]

If the index has name(s), you can even sort by **both** index and a column value. For example, the following sorts by both the index and the column `A` values:

```py
df = df.sort_values(['lvl_0', 'A'])
```

If you have a **MultiIndex** dataframe, then, you can sort by the index level by using the `level=` parameter. For example, if you want to sort by the second level in descending order and the first level in ascending order, you can do so by the following code.

```py
df = df.sort_index(level=[1, 0], ascending=[False, True])
```

[image: res2]

If the indices have names, again, you can call `sort_values()`. For example, the following sorts by indexes `'lvl_1'` and `'lvl_2'`.

```py
df = df.sort_values(['lvl_1', 'lvl_2'])
```