# sort pandas dataframe indeces

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe `df` which indeces are

```
df.index
Out[4]: 
Index([u'2015-03-28_p001_2', u'2015-03-29_p001_2',
       u'2015-03-30_p001_2', u'2015-03-31_p001_2',
       u'2015-03-31_p002_3', u'2015-04-01_p001_2',
       u'2015-04-01_p002_3', u'2015-04-02_p001_2',
       u'2015-04-02_p002_3', u'2015-04-03_p001_2',
       ...
       u'2016-03-31_p127_1', u'2016-04-01_p127_1',
       u'2016-04-01_p128_3', u'2016-04-02_p127_1',
       u'2016-04-02_p128_3', u'2016-04-03_p127_1',
       u'2016-04-03_p128_3', u'2016-04-04_p127_1',
       u'2016-04-05_p127_1', u'2016-04-06_p127_1'],
      dtype='object', length=781)
```

The dataframe df is the results of a merge of 2 dataframes.

As you can see from the indeces are not sorted. E.g. `'2015-03-31_p002_3'`(5th position) comes before `'2015-04-01_p001_2'` (6th position)

I would like to group together all the _p001_2 and sort them according to the date, then all the _p002_3, etc etc.

But I didnt manage to do it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, pandas: how to sort dataframe by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211737/python-pandas-how-to-sort-dataframe-by-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) is not possible use, then it is a bit complicated - need create helper `DataFrame` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
idx = pd.Index([u'2015-03-28_p001_2', u'2015-03-29_p001_2',
       u'2015-03-30_p001_2', u'2015-03-31_p001_2',
       u'2015-03-31_p002_3', u'2015-04-01_p001_2',
       u'2015-04-01_p002_3', u'2015-04-02_p001_2',
       u'2015-04-02_p002_3', u'2015-04-03_p001_2',

       u'2016-03-31_p127_1', u'2016-04-01_p127_1',
       u'2016-04-01_p128_3', u'2016-04-02_p127_1',
       u'2016-04-02_p128_3', u'2016-04-03_p127_1',
       u'2016-04-03_p128_3', u'2016-04-04_p127_1',
       u'2016-04-05_p127_1', u'2016-04-06_p127_1'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(len(idx))}, index=idx)
print (df)
                    a
2015-03-28_p001_2   0
2015-03-29_p001_2   1
2015-03-30_p001_2   2
2015-03-31_p001_2   3
2015-03-31_p002_3   4
2015-04-01_p001_2   5
2015-04-01_p002_3   6
2015-04-02_p001_2   7
2015-04-02_p002_3   8
2015-04-03_p001_2   9
2016-03-31_p127_1  10
2016-04-01_p127_1  11
2016-04-01_p128_3  12
2016-04-02_p127_1  13
2016-04-02_p128_3  14
2016-04-03_p127_1  15
2016-04-03_p128_3  16
2016-04-04_p127_1  17
2016-04-05_p127_1  18
2016-04-06_p127_1  19
```

---

```
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
                    a
2015-03-28_p001_2   0
2015-03-29_p001_2   1
2015-03-30_p001_2   2
2015-03-31_p001_2   3
2015-03-31_p002_3   4
2015-04-01_p001_2   5
2015-04-01_p002_3   6
2015-04-02_p001_2   7
2015-04-02_p002_3   8
2015-04-03_p001_2   9
2016-03-31_p127_1  10
2016-04-01_p127_1  11
2016-04-01_p128_3  12
2016-04-02_p127_1  13
2016-04-02_p128_3  14
2016-04-03_p127_1  15
2016-04-03_p128_3  16
2016-04-04_p127_1  17
2016-04-05_p127_1  18
2016-04-06_p127_1  19
```

---

```
df1 = df.index.to_series().str.split('_', expand=True)
df1[0] = pd.to_datetime(df1[0])
#if necessary change order columns for sorting 
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=[1,2,0])
print (df1)
                           0     1  2
2015-03-28_p001_2 2015-03-28  p001  2
2015-03-29_p001_2 2015-03-29  p001  2
2015-03-30_p001_2 2015-03-30  p001  2
2015-03-31_p001_2 2015-03-31  p001  2
2015-04-01_p001_2 2015-04-01  p001  2
2015-04-02_p001_2 2015-04-02  p001  2
2015-04-03_p001_2 2015-04-03  p001  2
2015-03-31_p002_3 2015-03-31  p002  3
2015-04-01_p002_3 2015-04-01  p002  3
2015-04-02_p002_3 2015-04-02  p002  3
2016-03-31_p127_1 2016-03-31  p127  1
2016-04-01_p127_1 2016-04-01  p127  1
2016-04-02_p127_1 2016-04-02  p127  1
2016-04-03_p127_1 2016-04-03  p127  1
2016-04-04_p127_1 2016-04-04  p127  1
2016-04-05_p127_1 2016-04-05  p127  1
2016-04-06_p127_1 2016-04-06  p127  1
2016-04-01_p128_3 2016-04-01  p128  3
2016-04-02_p128_3 2016-04-02  p128  3
2016-04-03_p128_3 2016-04-03  p128  3
```

---

```
df = df.reindex(df1.index)
print (df)
                    a
2015-03-28_p001_2   0
2015-03-29_p001_2   1
2015-03-30_p001_2   2
2015-03-31_p001_2   3
2015-04-01_p001_2   5
2015-04-02_p001_2   7
2015-04-03_p001_2   9
2015-03-31_p002_3   4
2015-04-01_p002_3   6
2015-04-02_p002_3   8
2016-03-31_p127_1  10
2016-04-01_p127_1  11
2016-04-02_p127_1  13
2016-04-03_p127_1  15
2016-04-04_p127_1  17
2016-04-05_p127_1  18
2016-04-06_p127_1  19
2016-04-01_p128_3  12
2016-04-02_p128_3  14
2016-04-03_p128_3  16
```

EDIT:

If duplicates, then is necessary create new columns, sort and last drop them:

```
df[[0,1,2]] = df.index.to_series().str.split('_', expand=True)
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
df = df.sort_values(by=[1,2,0])
df = df.drop([0,1,2], axis=1)
print (df)
                    a
2015-03-28_p001_2   0
2015-03-29_p001_2   1
2015-03-30_p001_2   2
2015-03-31_p001_2   3
2015-04-01_p001_2   5
2015-04-02_p001_2   7
2015-04-03_p001_2   9
2015-03-31_p002_3   4
2015-04-01_p002_3   6
2015-04-02_p002_3   8
2016-03-31_p127_1  10
2016-04-01_p127_1  11
2016-04-02_p127_1  13
2016-04-03_p127_1  15
2016-04-04_p127_1  17
2016-04-05_p127_1  18
2016-04-06_p127_1  19
2016-04-01_p128_3  12
2016-04-02_p128_3  14
2016-04-03_p128_3  16
```